# Android Studio Socket issues. Cannot resolve libcore.util.Objects

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have an android app sending data to a cpp server running on a Raspberry Pi. It was working fine until I updated Android Studio and now I get this error: `Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate android.system.StructAddrinfo.toString()`

I set a breakpoint at the `Socket sock = null;` (see below) line and clicked step into until I got to `StructAddrinfo.java` (see below) which is where I get the error listed above. In this file, `libcore.util.Objects` cannot be resolved.

I've been trying to fix it for hours but no luck...

Client.java:

```
package com.senoirdesign.seniorassistant;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

/**
 * Created by toddf on 11/20/2017.
 */

/* class for socket stuff */
public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String ip_addr;
    int port_num;
    String msg;

    /* Constructor for Client class */
    Client(String ip, int port, String message) {
        ip_addr = ip;
        port_num = port;
        msg = message;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {

        Socket sock = null;

        try {
            sock = new Socket(ip_addr, port_num);
            DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            DOS.writeUTF(msg);
            DOS.flush();
            sock.close();
        } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

StructAddrinfo.java:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.system;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import libcore.util.Objects;

/**
 * Information returned/taken by getaddrinfo(3). Corresponds to C's {@code struct addrinfo} from
 * <a href="http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/netdb.h.html">&lt;netdb.h&gt;</a>
 *
 * TODO: we currently only _take_ a StructAddrinfo; getaddrinfo returns an InetAddress[].
 *
 * @hide
 */
public final class StructAddrinfo {
  /** Flags describing the kind of lookup to be done. (Such as AI_ADDRCONFIG.) */
  public int ai_flags;

  /** Desired address family for results. (Such as AF_INET6 for IPv6. AF_UNSPEC means "any".) */
  public int ai_family;

  /** Socket type. (Such as SOCK_DGRAM. 0 means "any".) */
  public int ai_socktype;

  /** Protocol. (Such as IPPROTO_IPV6 IPv6. 0 means "any".) */
  public int ai_protocol;

  /** Address length. (Not useful in Java.) */
  // public int ai_addrlen;

  /** Address. */
  public InetAddress ai_addr;

  /** Canonical name of service location (if AI_CANONNAME provided in ai_flags). */
  // public String ai_canonname;

  /** Next element in linked list. */
  public StructAddrinfo ai_next;

  @Override public String toString() {
    return Objects.toString(this);
  }
}
```

Gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.senoirdesign.seniorassistant"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Gradle (Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem. After trying lots of things I followed these steps https://teamtreehouse.com/community/getting-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-after-converting-android-project-form-eclipse-to-android-studio-with-gradle to update the Compile SDK version and Build Tools version of my project and then I did File -> Invalidate Cache & Restart. That fixed it.